# JTable not visible in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jpanel

As I am a beginner with java swing (I'm using netbeans), I am having trouble integrating tables in my gui. 
I have a tab with a panel with research options in a db, and I want to add beneath this panel the produced table with the research results.
With swing, i have put a JPanel 'researchPanel' within my tab and what I do is the following:

```
        table = my_research_function(options);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setViewportView(table);
        //resultsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        resultsPanel.add(pane);

        // I'm just using this to ensure i get a table 
        // with correct results - works fine
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
```

As I saw in the produced code by swing, `resultsPanel` already has a layout. Just in case, i did a `resultsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout())` and `resultsPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER)` and I saw some shades in my panel but still no data.

Furthermore, in the Design tab of netbeans, I've set the panel to Auto-Resize both Vertical and Horizontal as the results table can be quite big. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing component can have only one parent component.

You can't see your `JTable` in `resultsPanel` because of the following reasons

At first you create `JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);`

which add to `resultsPanel`,

but then you override parent component of your `table` here `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));`.

So remove last line and your `JTable` will be visible.

Comment: tons of thank you! :) I don't know how many relevant topics I read before i posted here and couldn'n manage to solve my problem..